# Having trouble showing data of database tables using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having a issue in an ASP.NET Core web application where I want to show all the data that is in 2 different database tables (using Linq join).

I have a "General" view model that contains reference to other 2 view models, in this case my "General" view model is `UserReadvisorViewModel` with references to `UserViewModel` and `ReadvisorViewModel`

General view model:

```
public class UserReadvisorViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel UserViewModel { get; set; } = null!;
    public ReadvisorViewModel ReadvisorViewModel { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

User view model:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}
```

Readvisor view model:

```
public class ReadvisorViewModel
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    ...
}
```

The problem is when trying to make a join of both tables and then assign the result in a list with `.ToList()` so in the view I can see the results in a foreach

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<UserReadvisorViewModel> lst;

    using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
    {
        lst = (from a in db.Users
               join b in db.Readvisors
                      on a.Id equals b.Id
               select new UserReadvisorViewModel
                      {
                          UserViewModel =
                              {
                                  Username = a.Username
                                  ...
                              },

                          ReadvisorViewModel =
                              {
                                  Name = b.Name,
                                  ...
                              }
                        }).ToList();
    }

    return View(lst);
}
```

I get this error

> System.ArgumentException: 'must be reducible node'

Comment: i see no problem in above query. i suspect initialization of other properties  on `UserviewModel` or  `ReadViserViewModel` are complex and creating this problem

Comment: What are the other setter expressions on your output that you've excluded for brevity? Searching for 'must be reducible node' wasn't very insightful but did seem to have a common theme of referring to the products of join and group expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried as below:

Dbcontext:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext(DbContextOptions<SomeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Readvisor> Readvisor { get; set; }
}
```

in appsettings.json:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MVCViewComponentProjContext-e1efb976-a7c9-4d8a-bd15-fd573ea70261;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

regist in startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {                
            services.AddDbContext<MVCViewComponentProjContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SomeContext")));
        }
```

In controller:

```
 public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SomeContext _context;

        public UsersController(SomeContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        
        public IActionResult Index()
        {   
            
            var vm = (from a in _context.User
                            join b in _context.Readvisor on a.Id equals b.Id
                          select new UserReadvisorViewModel
                          {
                              UserViewModel = new UserViewModel{ Id = a.Id, Username = a.Username },
                              ReadvisorViewModel = new ReadvisorViewModel{Id=b.Id,Name=b.Name }
                          }).ToList();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

In your case,
The codes below would cause an error(not the error you mentioned) ,you have to create a instance of UserViewModel and UserViewModel

```
UserViewModel =
                              {
                                  Username = a.Username
                                  ...
                              },
```

When it comes to why you got the error, I think you need provide more details

Comment: Just adding a new instance of the "UserViewModel" and "ReadvisorViewModel" the problem is solved. Thank you!